# druid groupBy query - json syntax - intervals

Tags: druid

Im attempting to create this query (which works as I hope)

> SELECT userAgent, COUNT(*) FROM page_hour GROUP BY userAgent order by 2 desc limit 10

as a json. I've tried this:

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "page_hour",
  "granularity": "hour",
  "dimensions": ["userAgent"],
  "aggregations": [
    { "type": "count", "name": "total", "fieldName": "userAgent" }
    ],
"intervals": [ "2020-02-25T00:00:00.000/2020-03-25T00:00:00.000" ],
"limitSpec": { "type": "default", "limit": 50, "columns": ["userAgent"] },
"orderBy": {
    "dimension" : "total",
    "direction" : "descending"
}
}
```

but instead of doing the aggregation over the full range it appears to pick an arbitrary time span (EG 2020-03-19T14:00:00Z)

Answer (score 0):

If you want results from the entire interval to be combined in a single result entry per user agent, set `granularity` to `all` in the query.

Comment: Similar results - date/time span has changed to 2020-02-25. Still appears to be one day worth of data.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on Druid queries:

You can generate a native query by entering a SQL statement in the management console and selecting the explain/plan menu option from the three-dot menu by the run button.

It's worth confirming expectations that the `count` query-time aggregator will return the number of database rows (not the number of ingested events).  This could be the reason the resulting number is smaller than anticipated.

A `granularity` of `all` will prevent bucketing results by hour.

A `fieldName` spec within the `count` aggregator? I don't know what behavior might be defined for this, so I would remove this property.  The docs:

- see: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/aggregations.html#count-aggregator